# Derivative of log $x_i$ inside a $\log \sum$ of $x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms, chain-rule

I'm trying to differentiate the following:

$\frac{\delta}{\delta \log x_m} \log \sum_{m=1}^M x_m^k \, f(y_m)$

So we only care about a particular index of $x$, and $k$ is a constant. I'm stumped at how to take the derivative of $\log x_m$. Since I can't push the $\log$ inside the sum, how can I even obtain $\log x_m$? I thought maybe the chain rule could apply here, but it's not obvious to me how that would work in this instance either.

Comment: You are using m both as an index of summation and as a subscript outside the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $x_j^k=(e^{\log(x_j)})^k=e^{k\log(x_j)}$, so that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\log(x_i)}e^{k\log(x_j)}
=
\delta_{ij}ke^{k\log(x_j)}
=
\delta_{ij}kx_j^k.
$$
If you change your summation index from $m$ to $j$ for clarity, you get
$$
\begin{split}
&\frac{\partial}{\partial \log x_m} \log\left(\sum_{j=1}^M x_j^k \, f(y_j)\right)
\\=&
\frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial \log x_m}\sum_{j=1}^M x_j^k \, f(y_j)}{\sum_{j=1}^M x_j^k \, f(y_j)}
\\=&
\frac{kx_m^k \, f(y_j)}{\sum_{j=1}^M x_j^k \, f(y_j)}
\end{split}
$$
if everything is positive so the logarithms make sense.

Comment: That's brilliant! Thank you!